# Cesium czml change orientation of 3d model (gltf/glb) along with position in time

Tags: cesiumjs, czml, gltf

I have implemented a 3d model (cesium air) aircraft to move along a path. Its position is being changed based on time and the detailed data is available in the czml file under position attribute. However, I am not able to change the orientation of the aircraft along with path. The aircraft flies through the path but its heading , pitch and roll are constant. It does not pitch up with increase in height etc. How to implement the attitude changes using orientation attribute in the czml file or any other solution for the said problem?

Answer (score 3):

You need to assign a [VelocityOrientationProperty](http://cesiumjs.org/Cesium/Build/Documentation/VelocityOrientationProperty.html) to each entity (aircraft) that needs to orient itself along the path.  Unfortunately there's no CZML indicator for this, but you can assign it in client-side code after loading the CZML.

The [Sandcastle Interpolation Demo](http://cesiumjs.org/Cesium/Apps/Sandcastle/index.html?src=Interpolation.html&label=All) shows VelocityOrientationProperty applied to a moving aircraft.  Be sure to select a non-linear interpolation so it looks cool.

Comment: Thanks a lot emackey. I went through the interpolation example in sandcastle. Helped a lot.

Comment: @DragonFury would it be possible to post the way you solved this problem? even with a simple test case? :)